How to make generic callback function type work
The following example says it all:
function fn<R>(cb: <S1 extends string>(string: S1) => R) {
  return <S2 extends string>(str: S2) => cb(str)
}

const f = fn((passedString) => {
  return { passedString }
})

// I expect an error: This comparison appears to be unintentional ... but there's
// no error which means `passedString` is not known to be of type `""`
export const someValue = f("").passedString === "dfafa"


I would expect f("").passedString to be of type "", but it looks like the compiler couldn't pick the value of type S1 after the call to fn. Is there any way to get around this?
Update
I am aware that I can achieve the desired behaviour by placing the type parameter on the callback function itself passed to fn as also mentioned in @jesus Diaz Rivero answer below. However, all parameters to the callback must be explicitly typed in such case, which I'm trying to avoid.
function fn<R, V>(cb: (number: number, value: V) => R) {
  return (number: number, str: V) => cb(number, str)
}

// `number` must be typed explicitly
const f = fn(<V>(number: number, passedValue: V) => {
  return { number, passedValue }
})

export const someValue = f(8, "" as const).passedValue === "dfafa" // correctly errors

In this case, I would like the number parameter to not have to be explicitly typed when calling fn, but instead taken from the type signature of fn. In my case, the extra parameter (also the first parameter) is not as simple as number. If the callback were not generic, it would work, but with the introduction of <V>, it doesn't.
PS: The actual function I'm working with is a create method on a builder that takes advantage of the type info on the builder to specify the types of the parameters of the callback, and returns a middleware. The middleware is used as a function call. It looks something like:
export const builder = {
  // Rather than `number`, the actual type is based on type parameters on the builder
  // which I don't want caller to explicitly specify
  create<R, P extends unknown[]>(cb: (opts: number, ...params: P) => R) {
    return (...params: P) => {
      // Actual middleware
      return (opts: number) => cb(opts, ...params)
    }
  }
}


I put this in the typescript playground. It is inferring passedString to be a string and should be working without errors.

It takes it as string because of the constraint on type S1 not because I passed a string argument. If it took the type from the parameter, then the type of passedString should be "" and should cause an error when compared with "dfafa"

In order to let TS correctly infer the type you should the S1 generic parameter to be part of fn:
function fn<R, S1 extends string>(cb: (input: S1) => R) {
  return cb
}

const f = <T extends string>(passedString: T) => {
  return { passedString }
}

// Non-callback version correctly throws error
const someValue = f("").passedString === "da";
// Callback version now throws error
const someCallbackValue = fn(f)("").passedString === "da";

Note I have simplified fn since it seems to be a bit redundant to return a function which returns the callback.

I guess I should have given more context. Basically, the actual implementation i have requires that the type parameter lives on the callback type, because the i want the callback function passed to not have to deal with the types of the parameters passed to it as those are somewhat complex and are based on multiple other things.

This is the correct answer here, and the only way TS will ever transform a generic function the way you want. @Abdulramonjemil if you have some other requirement, please edit the question to explain, but note that it probably will be impossible if you add constraints on the already barely-possible task of having TS transform generic function types.

@jcalz I've updated the question. And yes, I think it's pretty clever that TS automatically makes the return type of fn generic if the callback is generic, and anything more than that is not probably not feasible. So, I'll just make it easier to explicitly define the types of other parameters.
